# Change comment symbol in Xtext editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext, emf

I have an Xtext grammar and the generated editor elements. The parser knows that comments start with "--" but hitting Ctrl+7 does insert "//". Also, the green, italic highlighting of comments does only happen with "//" and not with "--". Where can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do not want to override SL_COMMENT then you have to hook into the corresponding places

- for the highlighting: DefaultAntlrTokenToAttributeIdMapper
- for the toggle sl comment action: ISingleLineCommentHelper.getDefaultPrefixes(ISourceViewer, String)

Comment: I am ok with changing the rule, but I think it is alright. But I think the SL_COMMENT rule is alright, it does say, that "--" should be a comment. Also the parsers knows that, lines starting with -- are correctly handled as comments; only ctrl+7 and the correct highlighting does not work with "--", but when using "//". But lines starting with "//" are only highlighted as comments but are not ignored.

Comment: as said before. there are two ways to solve this - simply pick one

Answer (score 1):

have you overridden the SL_COMMENT rule?

If you want to insert "--" instead of "//", "--" should be the first alternative in SL_COMMENT rule:

```
terminal SL_COMMENT:
    ('--'|'//') !('\n'|'\r')* ('\r'? '\n')?
;
```

Comment: No, this seems to be the solution, but where can I change that rule? Should I do so in the generated files?

Comment: You just have to write your own terminal SL_COMMENT in your grammar file, it will override the default one.

Comment: In the *.xtext I found such a rule, it did specify "--" as a comment, but the highlighting/Ctrl+7 doesn't work anyway. The parser works all fine, ignoring comments, it's just the highlighting that does not work.